# Custom CodeIgniter route regex

Tags: regex, codeigniter, routes, clean-urls

Trying to improve a custom codeigniter route regex that I have created. Essentially the purpose of the custom route is to create a cleaner/shorter URL for client profile pages which have the format of `clients/client-slug`, for example: `clients/acme-inc`. I only want this route to match if their are no additional segments after the client-slug segment, and if they client-slug value does not match any of the 'reserved' values which correspond to actual methods/routes in the Clients controller. Currently, this is what I'm using:

```
$route['clients/(?!some_method|another_method|foo|bar)(.+)'] = 'clients/index/$1';
```

This mostly works ok, except for when there is a client-slug that begins with one of the reserved methods text, i.e. `clients/food-co`, which since it has `clients/foo` in it, the custom route is not matched. So I need to basically conditionally allow the route to contain any of the reserved methods in that set ONLY IF it is followed by additional characters (that is not a `/`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you try this?

```
$route['clients/(?!(?:some_method|another_method|foo|bar)(?:/|$))(.+)'] = 'clients/index/$1';
```

Comment: I just tried this solution but it does not appear to work, as the client slug can contain dashes, which is a non-word character, so, for example `clients/foo-inc` would not match the route when it should be.

Comment: @BillDami: I will put a /|$ instead.

Comment: that seems to be working with the URLs I've tested so far, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the [`_remap()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) method in the future. It will allow you to update your controller and add new methods without needing to update your route (you actually wouldn't need a route at all, so long as your URI matches the controller name).